# Cannot parse JSON data correctly

Tags: ios, json, swift

I've been trying to parse this JSON data, but for some reason have not been able to. The code and JSON that I have are below. I want it to show each page in pages and print it to the console. The code works, it just doesn't actually process anything after the if let pages = JSON[] (or so it seems,) because it won't print my for loop or page in pages. Code and JSON is below.

Here's the JSON data I'm trying to parse:

```
{"43993167":{"summonerId":43993167,"pages":[{"id":54725209,"name":"Jinx","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5337},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5337},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5337}]},{"id":54725210,"name":"support","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5255},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5255},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5255},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5255},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5255},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5255},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5347},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5365},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5365}]},{"id":64389802,"name":"Twisted Fate","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5315},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5315},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5315},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5315},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5315},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5365},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5365},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5365}]},{"id":69919016,"name":"Ahri","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5357},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5357},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5357}]},{"id":71240898,"name":"Gragas","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5316},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5357},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5357},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5357}]},{"id":71240899,"name":"Zac","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5318},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5325},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5296},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5357},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5357},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5357}]},{"id":71240900,"name":"Volibear","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5247},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5289},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5365},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5365},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5365}]},{"id":71240901,"name":"I AM SMURF","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5273},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5298},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5357},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5357},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5357}]},{"id":71240902,"name":"Graves","current":true,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5337},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5337},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5335}]},{"id":71240903,"name":"Vi","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5295},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5335},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5335},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5335}]},{"id":71240904,"name":"Reksai","current":false,"slots":[{"runeSlotId":1,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":2,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":3,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":4,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":5,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":6,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":7,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":8,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":9,"runeId":5245},{"runeSlotId":10,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":11,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":12,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":13,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":14,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":15,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":16,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":17,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":18,"runeId":5317},{"runeSlotId":19,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":20,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":21,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":22,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":23,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":24,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":25,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":26,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":27,"runeId":5290},{"runeSlotId":28,"runeId":5335},{"runeSlotId":29,"runeId":5335},{"runeSlotId":30,"runeId":5335}]}]}}
```

Here's my code for trying to parse it:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { data, response, error in

        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {

            switch httpResponse.statusCode {

            case 200..<300:

                if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? [String : AnyObject] {

                    println("json working") //this is as far as it will go, won't process the next part

                    //println(json)

                    if let pages = json["pages"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {


                        println("stat summary working")


                        for page in pages {

                            println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")

                            println(page)


                        }
                    }
                }


            default: println("Not Ok")

            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

URL is just the URL that shows the JSON data that I posted above the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work. Had to change the code a little bit. Here's how it looks now:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { data, response, error in

        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {

            switch httpResponse.statusCode {

            case 200..<300:

                if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary, let include = json.objectForKey("\(self.idNumber)") as? NSDictionary {

                    println("json working")

                    //println(json)

                    if let pages = include["pages"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {


                        println("stat summary working")


                        for page in pages {

                            println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")

                            println(page)


                        }
                    }
                }


            default: println("Not Ok")

            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not accessing your json correctly, by that I mean the path you provide in `json["pages"]` is not a valid one. Look at the data closer; `{"43993167":{"summonerId":43993167,"pages"`

You have an object, inside it the first thing is another object with the name/key "43993167", under that it has `pages`. So you would need `json["43993167"]["pages"]` to access the data you're trying to reach.

That being said, I can tell just by assumption you're dealing with a dictionary of summoner objects where the key is the summonerid and then you're trying to look at their rune page data... A better design would be to deserialize into something that reflects that structure (like a dictionary of summoner objects) then iterate that dictionary.
Ultimately you have something like this;

```
rootLevelDictionary[]
    summoner
        summonerId
        pages[]
           id
           name
           current
           slots[]
              runeObject
                 runeSlotId
                 runeId
```

That's the basic structure of your json. If I have time I'll turn it into a valid json-schema but hopefully that is enough to get you unblocked.

Comment: I tried doing json["43993167"]["pages"], but it fails the program and says "Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Because `json["pages"]` doesnt exist, its nested inside "43993167".

`json["43993167"]["pages"]` is what you need